# Derivative of a constant is not zero

Tags: integration, derivatives, definite-integrals

**From my book**

> From The First Mean Value Theorem we deduce the means value theorem for derivatives (the law of the mean):
> $$
> f(c)=\frac{1}{b-a} \int_{a}^{b} f(x) d x
> $$
> Let us differentiate the two members of the equation : $f^{\prime}(c)=\frac{1}{b-a} \int_{a}^{b} f^{\prime}(x) d x$
> $$
> \Rightarrow f^{\prime}(c)=\frac{1}{b-a}[f(x)]_{a}^{b}=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}
> $$

How can we differentiate constants (definite integral is a constant and $f(c)$ is a constant)?! Isn't that 0=0?

Comment: This is in your book? Which book are we talking about?

Comment: What a terrible explanation! You should find a better book... What they should have said is that they apply the mean value theorem for integrals to the function $f'$.

Comment: Also, I think the two c's represent different numbers.

Comment: @Thomas, this is my professor's book (not a famous book)

Comment: @HansLundmark can you give an answer elaborating your comment?

Comment: @bjorn93 what do you mean?

Answer (score 2):

The equation you are starting out with is a property of continuous functions. For a continuous funtion $f$, choose some points $a < b$ such that $[a,b]$ is a subset of the domain of definition, and then it is a true statement that there exists a number $c\in [a,b]$ such that
$$ f(c) = \frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b f(t) dt$$
The number $c$ will usually depend in an unknown way on $a, b, $ and $f$ and need not be unique.

As you are correctly noted, the elements of this equation are considered constant, there is nothing which you may want to differentiate here (as you would get $0$ on each side).

What Hans Lundmark is pointing out in his comment is that you may apply this same statement to $f^\prime$, if that is a continuous function. You get exactly the same statement with $f^\prime$ instead of $f$ and a potentially different value of $c$ (which now depends on $a, b$ and $f^\prime$).
In that case you may, in fact, apply the fundamental theorem of calculus which then yields, for a continuously differentiable function $f$.
$$\exists\, c\in[a,b]:\quad f^\prime(c) = \frac{f(b)-f(c)}{b-a}$$
But this is a rather poor version of that theorem, since it assumes that $f^\prime$ is continuous. One can do better rather easily, see [this wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem).

Comment: Alright thanks a lot